# mp3 encoder parameters and settings

Tags: android, mp3, encoder, lame

I tried to encode an mp3 sound in android device so I used lame encoder, it was successful but there are some settings and parameters for encoding like sample rate, bitrate and etc, I searched to find what they are and what choices is possible but I do not find something good, can anyone help me with them?

Here they are:

```
public static final int NUM_CHANNELS = 1;
public static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 16000;
public static final int BITRATE = 128;
public static final int MODE = 1;
public static final int QUALITY = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out more about these parameters, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3 first. You may need to check more specific details on mp3 codec documentation, too.